# Как передать ссылку на Activity Presenter в Fragment Presenter

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger2

Всем привет, я создаю андроид приложение с архитектурой MVP. У меня есть `Activity` и у нее есть `Presenter`. `Activity` так же имеет `Fragment` и у `Fragment` тоже есть `Presenter` (буду называть `Activity.Presenter` и `Fragment.Presenter` во избежание путаницы). Задача состоит в следующем: передать из `Activity` или `Activity.Presenter` в `Fragment.Presenter` ссылку на `Activity.Presenter`. Однако, я не могу внутри `Fragment` пользоваться таким механизмм как `getActivity()`, так как `Fragment` не должен знать об `Activity`(воизбежании жестких зависимостей) а так же не могу делать `Activity.Presenter` Singleton'ом . Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли это как-то реализовать, я не против использовать dagger ну или что-то более простое. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Доброго времени суток. Что конкретно вы понимаете под "во избежании жестких зависимостей"? В принципе, фрагмент без активности не может существовать, так что зависимость у вас есть и жесткая. Что по поводу самого вопроса - создайте базовый класс для фрагментов и храните в нём callback, который реализует и передает активность фрагменту перед транзакцией. Если он нужен presenter-у, пусть фрагмент отдает его ему или как-то иначе присваивается. Ничего плохого в передаче данных сверху-вниз нет.

Comment: через getActivity() это и делается

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, неплохой способ организации MVP во взаимодействии activity->fragment - это создавать в `Activity.Presenter` `Fragment.Presenter`. Почему я считаю это корректно?

Во-первых, фрагмент порожден активити, является его частью => это вполне логично, что логика активити знает про фрагмент. Т.о. активити может управлять фрагментом, а фрагмент при необходимости может достучаться до `Activity.Presenter` через интерфейс с набором необходимых функций

Во-вторых, (из практических соображений, с чем я столкнулся) однажды придется позаботиться о сохранении состояния фрагмента и активити при повороте экрана. Т.к. обычно в приложении есть какая-то навигация, то получается с т.з. `Fragment.Presenter` переход на другой фрагмент и поворот экрана - одно и то же (отсоединение от MVP.view). Но с точки зрения андроида - это, естественно разные вещи, т.е. при переключении фрагментов `onSaveInstanceState` не вызывается (из логики, что пользователь может никогда не вернутся в этот фрагмент). Получится, что просто некуда сохранять состояние (и даже если получится что-то сделать в други функциях, то потом придется бороться со сворачиванием приложения и последующим разворачиванием)

Решение: аргрегировать `Fragment.Presenter` в `Activity.Presenter`. Таким образом жизненный цикл `Fragment.Presenter` привязан к жизненному циклу активити. Из такой конструкции появляется важный момент: единственное, что надо сделать при повороте экрана - активити в `onSaveInstanceState` вытаскивает из `Activity.Presenter` состояние своего презентера и всех дочерних. А в onCreate это состояние можно восстановить

Благодаря такой конструкции уменьшится количество кода и странных костылей

Comment: Вопрос в том, что мне, возможно, придется использовать fragment с другой activity. В Вашем случае, мне придется дублировать код fragment.presenter,  вставляя его в другой activity.presenter. А это не есть хорошо, но спасибо за ответ.